# Attribute only for Android Studio API 16 and above

Tags: android

Hello just a rookie programmer here my teacher said that we need to follow the instructions in developers.google.com but I have encountered an error while coding.

```
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
```

Error is: Attribute"parentActivityName is only used in API 16 (or higher)
But my teacher said we could only use API 10. I don't actually know what to do since I'm just new.

Answer (score 3):

All you need in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent

(including supporting API 10+)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work, but warning is still present after adding the parent activity meta-data

Answer (score 0):

As MarvinLabs said, you will have to take additional steps to ensure that the behavior you need works correctly across all API levels you want to support. As an aside though, don't worry too much about the warning once you've taken care of adding the  element, it's just the IDE warning you and it will not have an impact on the application.

Comment: Thanks :), I thoguht it have an effect when running the code in the emulator.